# Javascript: Subtracting minutes in MySQL Timestamp Format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to create a switch using a button that when I click it, it will get a current timestamp minus 10 minutes, then will query all the entry in the database starting from the said timestamp, I have a working javascript function but the problem is when the time is with less then 10 minutes (eg. 21:06:35), it displays negative value (21:-4:35) instead of (20:56:35). Here's my current code:

```
    var nowna = new Date();
    var month = nowna.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = nowna.getDate();
    var hour = nowna.getHours();
    var minute = nowna.getMinutes() - 10;
    var second = nowna.getSeconds();
    var nowna_init = nowna.getFullYear() + '-' +
        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + ' ' +
        ((''+hour).length<2 ? '0' :'') + hour + ':' +
        ((''+minute).length<2 ? '0' :'') + minute + ':' +
        ((''+second).length<2 ? '0' :'') + second;
        var start15 = nowna_init;
        console.log(start15);
```

this is what I am getting at the console log

```
    2017-05-20 21:-4:35
    2017-05-20 21:-4:44
    2017-05-20 21:-1:33
    2017-05-20 21:26:05
    2017-05-20 21:26:08
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `setMinutes` of the Date Object.

Use it like this:

```
var d = new Date("2017-05-20T13:03:35.310Z");
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 10);
console.log(d.getMinutes());
```

The hour will be updated too.

```js
var d = new Date("2017-05-20T13:03:35.310Z");
console.log(d.getMinutes()); // 3
console.log(d.getHours()); // 13
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 10);
console.log(d.getMinutes()); // 53
console.log(d.getHours()); // 12
```

**Note**: The hour result depends on your local timezone.

Comment: when I'm trying to use setMinutes, I always get this result

        2017-05-20 22:1495291218574:18
        2017-05-20 22:1495291229071:29

Comment: Try to run the code snippet I have added. Let me know it's work for you...